# JAVASCRIPT: EDGE change extension of file download

Tags: javascript, file, download, microsoft-edge

I have a problems with Microsoft Edge: when I do the download edge changes the extension of the file that I just have downloaded. With Chrome and Firefox I don't have this problems... I attach the code that I use:

```
a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "name.xxx";
a.target = '_blank';
a.download = "name.xxx";
a.type = ".icd";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
a.remove();
```

The structure of the file is an XML file, but it has his extension.
Can you help me??

Comment: If your link URL is for a file download, then what matters is what your *server* is doing with the response headers.

Comment: What version of Edge are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Edge 38.14393.1066.0

Comment: Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393

Comment: Ah, I see you're using the ".download" property. Well, according to MDN, * If the name is not a valid filename of the underlying OS, browser will adapt it.*  Also your "type" value doesn't look like a valid MIME type.

Comment: the file to be downloaded is on the same path of the page.... is on the same machine.... with chrome e firefox I've got any problems....

Comment: I added the type to try resolving the problem, but it remain.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that by the HTML5 standard the browser is allowed to alter the filename as it sees fit.

Comment: OK, so it isn't a way to resolve this problem easly.... it will very hard convince my customer about this! Thank you so much for the help! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm late, but this is a solution that works, I had the same error and I was able to solve it.

```
var blob = new window.Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

var a = document.createElement('a');
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
a.href = url;
a.download = filename + '.pdf' || 'download';
document.body.append(a);
a.click();
a.remove();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```